# Using Python to extract key/value pairs that are nested at arbitrary levels

Tags: python, json, list

I need to iterate through the elements in this response and convert them into a different structure for an outgoing payload. If there aren't separate Production and Development Keys to iterate through, than I need to just default the Environment value to "Production"

**Response**

```
[{
    "Mainframe": {
        "Production": [{
            "Host": "Alfa",
            "Response": "11ms"
        }, {
            "Host": "Beta",
            "Response": "10ms"
        }],
        "Development": [{
            "Host": "Amdar",
            "Response": "10ms"
        }]
    },
    "NT": {
        "Production": [{
            "Host": "IceOut",
            "Response": "10ms"
        }, {
            "Host": "IceInt",
            "Response": "10ms"
        }],
        "Development": [{
            "Host": "IceStage",
            "Response": "10ms"
        }, {
            "Host": "IceTest",
            "Response": "10ms"
        }]
    },
    "XML": [{
        "Host": "XMLDm",
        "Response": "10ms"
    }, {
        "Host": "XMLAm",
        "Response": "10ms"
    }]
}]
```

**New payload**

```
"rows":[
    {
        "Host Type": "Mainframe",
        "Environment": "Production",
        "Host Name": "Alfa",
        "Response": "11 ms"
    },
    {
        "Host Type": "Mainframe",
        "Environment": "Production",
        "Host Name": "Beta",
        "Response": "10 ms"
    }
]
```

**etc...**

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: and post expected output

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
import pprint

response = [{
    "Mainframe": {
        "Production": [{
            "Host": "Alfa",
            "Response": "11ms"
        }, {
            "Host": "Beta",
            "Response": "10ms"
        }],
        "Development": [{
            "Host": "Amdar",
            "Response": "10ms"
        }]
    },
    "NT": {
        "Production": [{
            "Host": "IceOut",
            "Response": "10ms"
        }, {
            "Host": "IceInt",
            "Response": "10ms"
        }],
        "Development": [{
            "Host": "IceStage",
            "Response": "10ms"
        }, {
            "Host": "IceTest",
            "Response": "10ms"
        }]
    },
    "XML": [{
        "Host": "XMLDm",
        "Response": "10ms"
    }, {
        "Host": "XMLAm",
        "Response": "10ms"
    }]
}]


payload = {
    "rows": []
}


## do first pass ##

for item in response:
    for host_type, host_type_details in item.items():
        if type(host_type_details) == list:
            item[host_type] = {"Production": host_type_details}

## now read the data ##
for item in response:
    for host_type, host_type_details in item.items():
        for environment, environment_details in host_type_details.items():
            for host_details in environment_details:
                host_name = host_details["Host"]
                response_time = host_details["Response"]

                obj = {
                    "Host Type": host_type,
                    "Environment": environment,
                    "Host Name": host_name,
                    "Response": response_time
                }

                payload['rows'].append(obj)

## now print payload ##
pprint.pprint(payload)
```

Output:

```
{'rows': [{'Environment': 'Production',
           'Host Name': 'Alfa',
           'Host Type': 'Mainframe',
           'Response': '11ms'},
          {'Environment': 'Production',
           'Host Name': 'Beta',
           'Host Type': 'Mainframe',
           'Response': '10ms'},
          {'Environment': 'Development',
           'Host Name': 'Amdar',
           'Host Type': 'Mainframe',
           'Response': '10ms'},
          {'Environment': 'Production',
           'Host Name': 'IceOut',
           'Host Type': 'NT',
           'Response': '10ms'},
          {'Environment': 'Production',
           'Host Name': 'IceInt',
           'Host Type': 'NT',
           'Response': '10ms'},
          {'Environment': 'Development',
           'Host Name': 'IceStage',
           'Host Type': 'NT',
           'Response': '10ms'},
          {'Environment': 'Development',
           'Host Name': 'IceTest',
           'Host Type': 'NT',
           'Response': '10ms'},
          {'Environment': 'Production',
           'Host Name': 'XMLDm',
           'Host Type': 'XML',
           'Response': '10ms'},
          {'Environment': 'Production',
           'Host Name': 'XMLAm',
           'Host Type': 'XML',
           'Response': '10ms'}]}
```

To deal with the issue of having lists and dictionaries, this makes a first pass to put any data which doesn't currently have an environment into an environment - you can see we turn `response` into this:

```
[{'Mainframe': {'Development': [{'Host': 'Amdar', 'Response': '10ms'}],
                'Production': [{'Host': 'Alfa', 'Response': '11ms'},
                               {'Host': 'Beta', 'Response': '10ms'}]},
  'NT': {'Development': [{'Host': 'IceStage', 'Response': '10ms'},
                         {'Host': 'IceTest', 'Response': '10ms'}],
         'Production': [{'Host': 'IceOut', 'Response': '10ms'},
                        {'Host': 'IceInt', 'Response': '10ms'}]},
  'XML': {'Production': [{'Host': 'XMLDm', 'Response': '10ms'},
                         {'Host': 'XMLAm', 'Response': '10ms'}]}}]
```

Now the `"XML"` data has an environment explicitly mentioned, so we can just loop through each response item, then each host type, then each environment, and then each specific host to create each data object, and add the objects to `payload["rows"]`.

Comment: Normalizing the response first seems obvious now. WAY less complicated than I was trying to make it. Thank you for the reply!